# C++ error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.4

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I recently built OpenCV 4.4 with some contributed modules, but I cannot call them from C++.

#### What I did

From the `make install` output:

```
...
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.4.0" to "/usr/local/lib"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/ximgproc.hpp
---
```

When I `ls` to check that the file is there:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.4
> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.4
```

But when I compile my code in `g++` with:

```
OBJS=frame_extractor.o
BIN=g++ frame_extraction.cpp
CFLAGS+=-Wfatal-errors
LDFLAGS+=-L/opt/vc/lib/ -lpthread
LDFLAGS+=-L/usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_ximgproc
LDFLAGS+=`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`

$(BIN) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(RPATH) $(INCLUDES) -o $(OBJS)
```

and compile my program which includes the following:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ximgproc.hpp"
```

I get the error in the title.

#### The Question

Why can't I grab this library?  Is there something funny going on with the symlinking I can check?  Am I missing something obvious?

#### What I've tried

1. Explicit path in `g++`

I attempted to add an `rpath` to my `Makefile` but that did not help.

```
RPATH+=-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.4
```

2. Confusing library names

I also checked that the code is calling `ximgproc` rather than `imgproc`, a similarly titled header.

3. Checking that the lib has content

Running:

```
cat /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.4
```

outputs the usual gobbledygook to the terminal one might expect from a binary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good night's sleep, I realized I didn't run `ldconfig` after installing the library.  I run that, and the problem in the OP goes away.